# Pro and Cons to create a REST architechture using [SPRING MVC] or [GWT + MVP] (and using spring ROO)?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-roo, gwt-mvp

I am asking this question because, I see that Roo include SPRING MVC and GWT...but
- GWT (on its website) shows an example of a MVP pattern but I think it is not comparable with the SPRING MVC framework (indeed Spring MVC has more features. I have never used it...but I read that it helps a lot to do website, and easily lets have a REST architecture (how to do as easily a REST architecture with GWT and a MVP plateform ?)...

Can you help me to choose between these technologies (taking care that I want to develop my app on GAE, and I will also want Mobile phone version) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not to use GWT with Roo, its GWT support extremely buggy at the moment. (Saying this as a big fan of Roo)

Also, REST is architectural style which embraces HTTP as an application protocol, not only as a transport protocol, meanwhile GWT is a framework, or rather a toolset for creating rich web application which use JavaScript as a frontend, one has basically nothing to do with the other. You *can* however use Spring MVC to build RESTful applications:

1. http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/
2. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html
3. http://www.oudmaijer.com/2010/01/16/spring-3-0-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/

Comment: ok, I agree with you for the REST question...but not for your GWT opinion. I have no experience in theses technologies but I have understood that ROO is removable...so it will not have consequences on GWT isn t it ?